# PresentationFramework.pdb Was Not Loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm coding a c# app in visual studio and i keep getting a `PresentationFramework.pdb Was Not Loaded` error when I compile in Debug mode.

I've looked everywhere online and I don't get the answer I'm looking for. My problem is that a new page pops up and shows the error, not the error list. I also don't reference the file in my code.

The error list shows that a file that I am trying to access isn't available because it is being used by another process, so I added the following in an attempt to get rid of the error:

```
while (IsFileLocked(new FileInfo(fileName)))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
        {
            FileStream stream = null;

            try
            {
                stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
                stream.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {

                return true;
            }

            //file is not locked
            return false;
        }
```

That still doesn't work.

The code mentioned above should, in theory, wait until the file is available but it doesn't.

Comment: You have to dispose of a Stream. Either declare it with a [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement or do it manually in a `try/finally` block. In any case, don't just `Close()` it.

Comment: No idea what `PresentationFramework.pdb` has to do with this, though. Are you using some 3rd-party control, by chance? (Telerik, DevExpress etc.?)

Comment: No, Not really. I'm only using VS.

Comment: `PresentationFramework` is part of a WPF project (of course it can also be referenced in WinForm project). What kind of UI framework are you using? It's clear that you're using Visual Studio, but some 3rd-party controls/assemblies can reference `PresentationFramework` or other asseblies that you didn't reference directly in your Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the hassle. I just figured it out. If you have this problem, just delete all the unnecessary files in your project directory (`C:\Users\YourUserName\source\bin\Debug` *YourUserName* being your username). This error occurred for me because I installed a package and deleted it without deleting the res of the files that were downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in XAML you would change `MainWindow.xaml` **file-name** and forget to change the appropriate startup name inside App.xaml(You can locate App.xaml inside your Project's Solution Explorer). The code inside App.xaml looks like the following(line 5):

```
<Application x:Class="TarneebGUI.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TarneebGUI"
         StartupUri="mainwindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
     
</Application.Resources>
```

This would also cause this problem.

SOLUTION: change this **mainwindow.xaml** to whatever the name of your starter file is/new name of MainWindow.xaml. It solved my problem, I guess this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Application x:Class="State.Pattern.Example.App" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    
    StartupUri="HERE INSERT PATH TO ONE OF THE MAIN WINDOWS BELOW">
    
<--Basic.Implementation/MainWindow.xaml-->
<--StatePattern.Implementation/MainWindow.xaml-->
<--Stateless.Implementation/MainWindow.xaml-->
<Application.Resources></Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

The OP who stated the StartupUri is incorrectly pointed is the common problem. Downloading this off Github when I put in the correct StartupUri it works correctly e.g. StartupUri="Basic.Implementation/MainWindow.xaml"